# Text won't appear on an html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two webpages made; they are index.html and about.html. They are in the same folder and the code for both sites is exactly the same. The problem is some text only shows up on the index.html page. The text that isn't showing up is the word "Menu" for my navigation bar, some place holder text in the body, and a welcome to the page header. I am using a style sheet to modify the text with CSS but still, i am using the exact same code on both pages.

I opened the about page with chrome inspect elements and found that the "Menu" text was actually showing up but was underneath an image I had on the site. The other text, however wasn't showing up at all. I have no idea why the text works fine on one page but not the other. Any help would be appreciated.

Code for the welcome in the index.html page and about page for the welcome text:

```
</b><div id="greeting"></div>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

code in main.js:

```
var element = document.querySelector("#greeting");
element.innerText = "Welcome to Prokéstrats!";
```

code in the style sheet:

```
#greeting {
background-color: #FFCC00;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 21px;
margin: 15px;
margin-left: 550px;
margin-right: 565px;
}
```

Edit: Thanks guys for suggestion innerHTML intead of innerText. It works perfectly now.

Comment: not enough information to provide an answer

Comment: Yes, you need to provide a demo of some sort, or a link at least. Try recreating the pages at CodePen or jsFiddle.

Comment: can you give an example on http://plnkr.co/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change **element.innerText** as:

```
var element = document.querySelector("#greeting");
element.innerHTML = "Welcome to Prokéstrats!";  // Update this line with innerHTML
```

That's it.